# how to map keys of the dictionary to a column values of pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas Dataframe with a column name `List_No` and its **values exactly match with the keys** of the dictionary (***not in order***). Values of dictionary are `np.array` of an RGB image. I want to add a new column (`img_array`) to my Dataframe based on values of column `List_No` and keys of the dictionary. I'll use `img_array` column's content later for CNN training.

Have a look at examples below:

**Dataframe**

```
Class  List_No    Height 
    1        1       167
    0       11       143
    1       15       178
```

**Dictionary**

```
#I replaced an actual array with "(224,224,3) array"
{'11': (224,224,3) array, '15': (224,224,3) array, '1': (224,224,3) array}
```

**Dataframe that I want** (with a new column `img_array`)

```
Class    List_No    Height    img_array            
    1          1       167    (224,224,3) array  # note that I'm using "(224,224,3) array" instead of full image array
    0         11       143    (224,224,3) array    
    1         15       178    (224,224,3) array
```

And yes I tried `map`:

```
data_frame['img_array'] = data_frame['List_No'].map(dictionary)
```

However, `img_array` column has `NaN` values and not throwing any error for tracing

```
Class    List_No    Height    img_array            
    1          1       167          NaN
    0         11       143          NaN    
    1         15       178          NaN
```

I suspect it is because the type of `List_No` is `int64` and key of the dictionary is `str` but I'm not sure what to do next.
Your help is appreciated very much, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to strings by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
#sample array
a  = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,6]])
dictionary = {'11': a, '15': a, '1': a}

data_frame['img_array'] = data_frame['List_No'].astype(str).map(dictionary) 
print (data_frame)
   lass  List_No  Height               img_array
0     1        1     167  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6]]
1     0       11     143  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6]]
2     1       15     178  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6]]
```

Or convert keys of dict to integers:

```
d = {int(k):v for k, v in dictionary.items()}   
data_frame['img_array'] = data_frame['List_No'].map(d)
print (data_frame)
   lass  List_No  Height               img_array
0     1        1     167  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6]]
1     0       11     143  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6]]
2     1       15     178  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to archive what you need is to use apply function, especially if you don't want to convert type of data in your dataframe.

If you use apply function, you can convert string only there - it saves memory if you don't want to convert data permanently.

Simple example:

```
dict = {'11': (224,224,3), '15': (224,224,3), '1': (224,224,3)}

df = pd.DataFrame({'List_No':[1,15,11],'something':[4,5,2]})

df['array'] = df['List_No'].apply(lambda x: dict[str(x)])

df

   List_No  something          array
0        1          4  (224, 224, 3)
1       15          5  (224, 224, 3)
2       11          2  (224, 224, 3)
```